# Raw types inside of generic definition

Tags: java, generics, types, raw-types, subtyping

I wonder why the following generic definition does not produce a compiler warning:

```
class MyClass<T extends List> { }
```

and how the above definition is different to

```
class MyClass<T extends List<?>> { }
```

Whenever you read about generics, you read about how raw types should be avoided and consequently, whenever you handle generic types, you get a compiler warning. The raw type inside of the first definition does however not create such a warning.

Secondly, I wonder how the exact subtyping definition between raw types and generic types are. According to [this summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), raw types are kind of an "opt-out" of type checking such that type checking is simply inactive whenever a raw type is involved. Is this assumption correct? And how does this effect the above "raw" generic definitions?

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**: I understand what you are saying. However, this is not what I am confused about. Look at this scenario:

```
class MyClass<T extends MyClass<T>> {}

public void callWildcard1(MyClass<?> node) {
    callBound1(node);
}

public <T extends MyClass<T>> void callBound1(T node) {
    // Do something
}

public void callWildcard2(MyClass<?> node) {
    callBound2(node);
}

public <T extends MyClass> void callBound2(T node) {
    // Do something
}
```

The first call from `callWildcard1` to `callBound1` is not allowed because of the generic constraint. The second is however allowed. How can I perform the first call without "inner raw types"? I don't see why the compiler would forbid the first. Shouln't any parameter valid wildcard parameter imply `? extends MyClass<?>`?

**UPDATE 2**: I found out by trial and error, that I can solve the problem by defining:

```
public <T extends MyClass<? extends T> void callBound2(T node) {
    // Do something
}
```

even though I do not quite understand why. But there is even more confusion, when looking at this example: (this is a very simple version of what I am actually trying to do.)

```
public void call() {
    genericCall1(new MyFilter<MyClass<?>>(), MyClass.class);
    genericCall2(new MyFilter<MyClass<?>>(), MyClass.class);
}

public <T extends MyClass<? extends T>> void genericCall1(MyFilter<T> filter, Class<? extends T> filterBoundary) {
  // Do something.
}

public <T extends MyClass<? extends T>, U extends T> void genericCall2(MyFilter<T> filter, Class<? extends U> filterBoundary) {
  // Do something.
}

class MyClass<T extends MyClass<T>> { }

class MyFilter<T extends MyClass<? extends T>> { }
```

Why is `genericCall1` prohibited and `genericCall2` is not? Again, I found the solution by an academic guess instead of true understanding. Sometimes, when working with Java and its generics I want to cry...

Comment: I a getting waring "List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized" with jdk 1.6

Comment: In first `MyClass` definition you are providing a type which is `List`, thats why you don't get a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when you use `class MyClass<T extends List> { }` inside `MyClass` you lose type safety.

for example:

```
class A <T extends List<?>>{
    void someFunc(T t) {
        t.add(new Object());//compilation error
    }

}

class B <T extends List>{
    void someFunc(T t) {
        //compiles fine
        t.add(new Object());
        t.add("string");
        t.add(new Integer(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this basically is the answer to my question. I refined my actual intent by another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061292/java-generics-raw-types-inside-of-generic-definition