# Generic types of type variables?

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

How would I express the following type relationship in Java generics:

```
class MyClass<T> { }

interface MyInterface<T extends MyClass> { 
  void m1(T<Integer> argument);
  void m2(T<String> argument);
  void m3(T<?> argument);
}
```

without a compiler complaint. Is that even possible? I want to make sure that all methods receive the same (sub)class of `MyClass` while not breaking type-safety. In the domain, different subclasses og `MyClass` would not make sence. Do I really have to list three generic type variables like this:

```
class MyClass<T> { }

interface MyInterface<T1 extends MyClass<Integer>, 
   T2 extends MyClass<String>, T3 extends MyClass<?>> { 
  void m1(T1 argument);
  void m2(T2 argument);
  void m3(T3 argument);
}
```

I feel like this is terrible to read and does neither express my intention as nicely as I wished. This question is related to my other question on generics [Raw types inside of generic definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061292/java-generics-raw-types-inside-of-generic-definition) which still confuses me. Maybe someone can help! Thank you.

Comment: You definitely can't do `T<>` with Java generics. Your solution is probably the best available workaround.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I have an interface with arround 20 different generic types... I hate using this interface and yet I need it. Either users dont get type safety or they type forever, both solutions are not quite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I realized that I get because I cannot express this in Java:

```
class MyClass<T> { }

interface MyInterface<T extends MyClass> { 
  T<S> m1(S argument);
}
```

However, I found a rather fancy solution to this. Instead of manually upgrading my return type in every subinterface, I use [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/Spoon/HomePage) to read and write the corresponding source code before compilation. The compiler sees my code as if I overrode the return types in every interface manually. This keeps my code in sync with the super interface on every Maven build and I do not have to worry about it any more.

This solution might not be for everybody, but it is the cleanest solution I could think of in the spirit of DNRY.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its a good way. I feel using below method you cannot "bind" the parameters `m1`, `m2`, `m3` method, instead while calling you can have privilege of using any kind of parameters be it `MyClass<Integer>` or `MyClass<String>`

```
public class MyClass<T> { }

interface MyOtherClass<T extends MyClass<?>> { 
  void m1(T argument);
  void m2(T argument);
  void m3(T argument);
}
```

And the implementer

```
class MyOtherClassImpl<T extends MyClass<?>> implements MyOtherClass<T> {

    @Override
    public void m1(T argument) {

    }

    @Override
    public void m2(T argument) {

    }

    @Override
    public void m3(T argument) {

    }

}
```

and this is how you can call

```
  MyOtherClass<MyClass<?>> otc = new MyOtherClassImpl<MyClass<?>>();
  MyClass<Integer> m1 = new MyClass<Integer>();
  MyClass<String> m2 = new MyClass<String>();
  MyClass<Object> m3 = new MyClass<Object>();
  otc.m1(m1);
  otc.m2(m2);
  otc.m3(m3);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I lose all type safety within `MyInterface`. I just have to assume that the constraints are set correctly and will otherwise get nasty `ClasscastException`s at runtime if not applied correctly. Also, this won't work when using the generic parameter as a return type when type-safety is of matter for the end user.